# How to reset $rootScope?

Tags: angularjs, rootscope, angularjs-rootscope

After user logs out, I need to clean up my $rootScope. I tried `$rootScope.$destroy()` but that didn't do the trick. Is there a way to loop through all the values in $rootScope and delete them or a method to simply reset it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may wish to retain the default values that come with `$rootScope` when it is initialized. Since they all begin with a `$` you can delete all the properties that don't start with `$`.

```
for (var prop in $rootScope) {
    if (prop.substring(0,1) !== '$') {
        delete $rootScope[prop];
    }
}
```

You could make it easy to call by adding it as a function on `$rootScope`.

```
$rootScope.$resetScope = function() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> - Indeed, the `$destroy()` method won't work on $rootScope (see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c6b4ab35/src/ng/rootScope.js#L470)). I've worked around that by invoking `$rootScope.$broadcast("$destroy")` rather than `.$destroy()` when eliminating an entire Angular instance on our app. This way, all destructors are invoked the same.
> - As for the element $destroy event, I have to admit I wasn't even aware of it just a few days ago… I hadn't seen it anywhere in the docs, plus I'm using jQuery so according to [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1512)  it wouldn't work for me anyway.

Reference from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1537)

That is long description, But you can manually clear the `RootScope` by using this below ways

### Option 1

**Clear  the rootScope variable**

```
$rootScope.currentStatus = ""; //or undefined
```

### Option 2

**if you want to remove whole $rootscope objects,**

```
 $rootScope=undefined //or empty
```

Comment: This no longer seems to be the case as of 1.6 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.x/src/ng/rootScope.js#L922-L927

Answer (score 2):

To delete a variable from rootScope

```
delete $rootScope.variablename
```